# Can I use Awesomium in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, webkit, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, awesomium

I want to use [Awesomium](http://wiki.awesomium.com/) [Webview](http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/) inside `Windows Store (Metro Style)` App. When I try  to import Awesomium DLLs to `Refrences` I get this error

`"The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario."`

I know "A Metro style app must use references to another .NETCore or Portable Library binary". How do I use Awesomium libraries inside Windows Store (Metro Style) App?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708921/adding-net-framework-dll-as-reference-to-windows-store-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's not something they support. They only support WPF, WinForms, MonoMac and Unity (source http://wiki.awesomium.net/)

You could try using the unity version inside a store app though.