# Unable to add reference to third party dll in a UWP project

Tags: c#, uwp

Since a `UWP` app is a `.NET Core` app, a reference to a third party `dll created in .NET 4.0` is not getting added in my UWP project in `VS2017`. I'm getting the error shown below. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14708921/1232087). But since that question is about 6 years old, and since then a lot has changed in the .NET Core world, I thought may be there are some better solutions to my problem than just rather complicated workarounds. Are there any simpler solutions to make a third party dll reference added to a UWP project?

**Error**:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid nothing is changed, because they target different frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a .NET Framework DLL to a UWP app.

The best/closest thing you can to is add a desktop extension to your UWP process, which is a separate process that can run the full .NET Framework on desktop and therefore load this DLL.

Here is a tutorial on desktop extension for UWP: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/